# How to execute a method by binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

A `ComboBox` and a `Button` are on different user controls and do not see each other. Both of them are bound to the same `ViewModel` though.

The `Button` has a Click event which executes a method in the code-behind of its user control.

I want to be able to execute this method when I change `ComboBox`. For example let's say the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` is bound to a property in `ViewModel`, now when it is changed, I want the method in the other control to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that these two controls are unaware of one another, but are bound to the same `ViewModel`. I've found the easiest way to execute some type of code upon a property changing is to execute it directly from the `set { }` access modifier. Consider the following:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private MyObject _currentObject;

    public MyObject CurrentObject
    {
        get { return this._currentObject; }
        set
        {
            this._currentObject = value;
            //Usually where OnPropertyChanged goes or however you implement INotifyPropertyChanged

            //Where we call our command, logic can be introduced if needed.
            //Also we may just call the method directly.
            this.SomeCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }

    private Command _someCommand;

    public Command SomeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this._someCommand ?? (this._someCommand = new Command(
                () =>
                {
                    this.SomeMethod();
                },
                () =>
                {
                    //The CanExecute test, returns bool.
                    return this._currentObject != null ? true : false;
                }));
        }
    }

    private string SomeMethod()
    {
        return "I just got called yo!";
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Since the code to execute exists in the handler you will have to do a little work to get this right. Even though this violates MVVM principals it will work:

1. You will need to move the code to execute to the `ViewModel` underneath a new method if not already done, let's stick with the `SomeMethod()` name.
2. You need to obtain a reference to the `ViewModel` in the handler. I'm assuming this is already set as the `DataContext`

   `MyViewModel viewModel = DataContext as MyViewModel;`
3. Next you will need to call that method from the handler:

   `viewModel.SomeMethod();`
4. Now you may call the method from the `set { }` portion of your property contained within the `ViewModel`.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight but my problem is that the method I'm trying to call is in the code-behind of the user control holding `Button`. Maybe it is because of the bad design on my part that this situation has happened. I'm using that button to update a drawing when clicked. And I also want to make this happen when changing the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

you would want to create an object (i.e. SelectedComboBoxItem) that raises property changed. then use the generated event to start the event trigger you are trying to create.